# Define ternary inline operator in F#

Tags: syntax, f#, operators

I want to define an infix operator `|>>` which works like this:

`i |>> f1 f2` is the same as `(f1 i, f2 i)`

i.e. it will apply an argument onto two functions and concatenate the results.

Best case would be to create a generic operator `|>>*` that would also take a binding operation `b` to give me an operator that works like this.

E.g. if `b = fun a b -> (a, b) // Concatenation operator`

`i (|>>* b) f1 f2` is the same as `i |>> f1 f2` is the same as `b (f1 i) (f2 i)`

I tried it the following way:

```
let (|>>*) (i: 'IN) (b : 'S -> 'T -> 'OUT) =
    fun (f1: 'IN -> 'S) (f2: 'IN -> 'T) ->
        b (f1 i) (f2 i)
        
let (|>>) i f1  =
    (|>>*) i (fun a b -> a,b) f1
        
let x =
    10 |>> (fun x -> x + 2) (fun x -> x + 2)
```

Unfortunately when testing this I still need to supply brackets like this:

```
let f1 = fun x -> x + 1
let f2 = fun x -> x - 1

10 |>> f1 f2 // Type resolvement returns error
(10 |>> f1) f2 // Works, returns (11,9)
```

I guess the error occurs because the operator does not have priority over function calls?

[image]

Comment: You can't. Ternary operators are not a thing in F#

Answer (score 2):

F# does have a ternary operator, `op_DynamicAssignment`, albeit it is very specialized.

```
let (?<-) a b c = b a, c a

10 ? ((+) 2) <- ((+) 2)  // val it : int * int = (12, 12)
(?<-) 10 ((+) 2) ((+) 2) // val it : int * int = (12, 12)
```

Comment: Is it possible to use any combinations of symbols here or do I have to override `op_DynamicAssignment` ?

Answer (score 1):

F# does not support ternary operators only binary.

The best you can do is wrap the functions in a tuple.

```
let (|>>) i (f1,f2)  = (f1 i, f2 i)
```